# initializing multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I am new to AngularJS.

to achieve a data-grid with a filter form I have created two directives in my main view.

myFilterForm - is a filter form for the data in the grid with the functions:

- filter() - fires a 'filterChanged' event with the form's model
- reset() - sets the form's model to the default values and calls
  filter().

in order to communicate the filter changes to the grid (and to other directives that were removed for simplification) these methods broadcast a 'filterChanged' event with the filter object:

```
    myApp.directive('myFilterForm', [function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl:  'partials/filter-form.html',
    scope: true, // use own scope
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        // Define a filter object for URL parameters
        scope.formObject = {};

        // Clear the filter:
        scope.resetFilter = function(){
            scope.formObject = angular.copy(scope.defaultFilter);
            scope.$parent.filterOn = false;
            scope.$parent.$broadcast('filterChanged', scope.formObject);
            scope.filterReset = true;
        }


        // Filter the data:
        scope.filter = function(){
            if(scope.filterForm.$dirty){
                scope.$parent.filterOn = true;
            }
            scope.filterForm.$setPristine(); // disable the filter button until some value changes (prevent multiple clicks)
            scope.$parent.$broadcast('filterChanged', scope.formObject);
            scope.filterReset = angular.equals(scope.formObject, scope.defaultFilter);
            console.log("filterReset="+scope.filterReset);
        }

    },
    controller: function($scope, $timeout){

        //TODO: HACK!!!
        var timer = $timeout(
            function() {

                console.log( "Timeout executed", Date.now() );
                $scope.formObject = angular.copy($scope.defaultFilter, $scope.formObject);
                $scope.filterReset = true;
                console.log(">>>>>>>LOADING>>>>>>"+angular.toJson($scope.formObject));
                $scope.$parent.$broadcast('filterChanged', $scope.formObject);

            },
            100
        );
    }
    }}]);
```

the (simplified) filter-form.html template:

```
    <div class="well">
    <form novalidate name="filterForm" novalidate class="form-horizontal" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formObject.firstName" class="form-control input-sm">
    </form>
    <button ng-click="resetFilter()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Reset</button>
    <button ng-click="filter()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i> Filter</button>
    </div>
```

myDataGrid - is a wrapper around ng-grid that uses server-side sorting and paging

in myDataGrid I handle the 'filterChanged' event by calling the $http to reload the grid's (filtered) data.

```
myApp.directive('myDataGrid', ['serverProxy', '$log', function (serverProxy, $log  ) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    template: '<div cg-busy="\'gridTracker\'" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>',
    scope: true, //ng-grid wrapper should use it own (child) scope (see:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/206)
    controller: 'gridCtrl',

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        if(attrs.apiUrl){
            scope.apiUrl = attrs.apiUrl;
        }

        // holds the item count in the DB with the current filter applied
        scope.totalServerItems = 0;
        // holds the filter form model
        scope.formObject =  {};
        // holds the sorting and paging settings
        scope.paramObject = { limit: scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, page: scope.pagingOptions.currentPage };


        // Watch for changes in ng-grid's currentPage
        scope.$watch('pagingOptions.currentPage', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                scope.paramObject.page = newVal;
                scope.loadData();
            }
        }, true);

        // Watch for changes in ng-grid's pageSize
        scope.$watch('pagingOptions.pageSize', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                scope.pagingOptions.currentPage = 1;// if pageSize changes - start from first page
                scope.paramObject.limit = newVal;
                scope.loadData();
            }
        }, true);

        scope.$watch('sortOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                $log.debug("sortOptions="+angular.toJson(scope.sortOptions.fields));
                scope.paramObject.sort = newVal.fields[0];
                scope.paramObject.direction = newVal.directions[0];
                scope.loadData();
            }
        }, true);


        scope.$on('filterChanged', function(event, filterObj) {
            $log.debug('myDataGrid: caught filterChanged event! - new val='+angular.toJson(filterObj));
            scope.pagingOptions.currentPage = 1;// if filter changes - start from first page
            scope.loadData(filterObj);
        });

        // Update the paging data for the grid:
        scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
            scope.myData = data.content;
            scope.totalServerItems = data.totalElements;
            if (!scope.$$phase) {
                scope.$apply();
            }
        };


        scope.loadData = function (formObject) {
            if(formObject) { scope.formObject = formObject; }
            serverProxy.getData(scope.apiUrl, scope.paramObject, scope.formObject, 'gridTracker', function(data){
                scope.setPagingData(data, scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, scope.pagingOptions.pageSizes);
            });
        };

    }
}}]);
```

the controller for the grid has some ng-grid default configuration:

```
myApp.controller('gridCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.pagingOptions = {
    pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 198],
    pageSize: 10,
    currentPage: 1
};

$scope.sortOptions = {
    columns: [],
    fields: [],
    directions: []
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: $scope.gridColumnDefs, // should be defined in the view's controller
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    sortInfo: $scope.sortOptions,//,
    useExternalSorting: true,
    i18n: "en"
};

}]);
```

and finally, the main view had both directives:

```
    <div my-filter-form></div>
    <div my-data-grid></div>
```

and is using a controller where I set the specific configuration for the page:

- the server URL to load the data
- the grid columns
- *the default filter*

  ```
  myApp.controller('ViewCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  // server URL to get the grid data:
  $scope.apiUrl = '/api/users';

  $scope.gridColumnDefs = [
  {field: 'firstName', displayName:'First Name', resizable: true, sortable: true},
  {field: 'lastName', displayName:'Last Name', resizable: true, sortable: true},
  {field: 'roles', displayName:'Roles', resizable: true, sortable: false, cellFilter: 'listProperty:\'name\''},
  {field: 'active', displayName:'Active', resizable: true, sortable: false, cellFilter: 'yesNoBoolean'},
  {field: 'updateDate', displayName:'Update Date', resizable: true, sortable: true, cellFilter: 'date:\'dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm:ss a\''}
  ];

  // default filter values 
  $scope.defaultFilter = {
      "firstName": "jimmy"
  };

  }]);
  ```

I would like the initial load of the page to load the grid and the form with default filter values applied.

my current solution is to set a short $timeout in the controller of myFilterForm directive which sets the default filter and fires the 'filterChanged' event. this works but it feels like a hack.

could someone suggest the proper way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not positive I understand the situation, but it sounds like you need a `$watch` in your directives so that you're not worried about timing. Things will update whenever they need to. Does that make sense? If so, I'll post an example as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you suggest I should watch and where.  could you please elaborate

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't be more specific without seeing your code. Could you make a demo on something like jsbin.com and strip out anything that isn't completely necessary?

Comment: thanks. I will create a plunker tomorrow. is jsbin better?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I like jsbin if it's really simple, but plnkr is SO awesome for having the create file functionality. If you can, try to generalize everything... it's ideal if you can create "dummy" directives that only do something related to the issue. I don't know if you get what I mean - but do your best and maybe it will work out! Overall, your issue sounds like a common one for people new to Angular. I never worry about timing. If things are set up well, they just work. Angular will update / execute things when it has what needs or something changes.

Comment: Holy wall of code - try and pare down things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a better solution that works and does not involve $timeout. (thanks m59)

in the 'myFilterForm' I removed the controller function and added the following watch in the link function:

```
scope.$watch('defaultFilter', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    scope.resetFilter();                
}, true);
```

the defaultFilter does not actually change - it is used to reset the filter back to the defaults. but angular calls the watch on the initial load which is what I need to reset the form and load the data